# Can't understand why my async await isn't working in my lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, async-await

so I have a lambda that take multiple buckets as a parameter and I want to loop through each bucket and push all entries into an array.

I understand that s3.listObjectsV2 is an async function so I have added an await infront of it but for some reason the code is still console logging allData first and then running the listObjects functions.

I don't understand why the async await isn't waiting for the listobjects to finish first and then moving on to the console.log(allData)

Here is the code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const S3 = new AWS.S3();


exports.listObjects = function(params) {
     return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
         var allData=[]
         
         for (const param of params){
          await S3.listObjectsV2(param, (err, data) => {
             if (err) return reject(err)
             allData.push(data)
             //resolve(data)    
            
         }) 
         }
         console.log(allData)
        
         
     })
 }
```

Comment: `(err, data) => {` is a callback, try `allData.push(await S3.listObjectsV2(param).promise())` instead, and dont forget to wrap in try/catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda handler itself should be async, and there you go:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.listObjects = async function(params) {
  const allData = [];
  for(const param of params) {
     const result = await S3.listObjectsV2(param).promise();
     console.log(result);
     allData.push(result);
  }
  return allData;
}
```

Comment: I was writing await but had not added .promise() so it was not working for me. Thanks for helping.